# can laravel include blade route from public file

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

i create file in public folder and try to include blade file

```
<?php include('../resources/views/template/header.blade.php'); ?>
```

its not working fine, css not render at this point.
Can anyone help me with this

Answer (score 1):

There's some differences between `html` and `blade` template. Laravel follows `blade` engine.

When you use php core `include()` function, it will parse the template as **plain php** and all of the blade syntax (e.g. @extends, @if...@else etc.) inside the file won't work.

I guess what you need is an equivalent of `include()` function in blade which is addressed as `@include()` in blade template.

Replace the code by the following,

```
@include('template/header.blade.php')
```

You don't need to add `resources/views` since by default `@include()` navigate to that dir.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work as the @if etc present in laravel's blade templates won't be executed if you run/include the PHP file directly. It should always be called as

```
view("my_page");
```

This view function takes the script in the my_page.blade.php file and processes it and produces the result.

If you want to create a public route e.g yoursite.com/my_page.php then it's better that you create a route for "/my_page.php" and then return the blade file using the view method. E.g

```
Route::get('/my_page.php', function () {
    return view('my_page');
});
```

I wont recommend you to put php files directly in the public folder.